# what is the derivative of the function $f(x)=2.5\sqrt{400-x^2}+1.5\left(80-x\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x)=2.5\sqrt{400-x^2}+1.5\left(80-x\right)$$

Please explain how you would find the derivative in the scenario, thanks

Comment: This is not an equation. An equation needs an equals. You have an expression.

Answer (score 2):

=$-2.5(400-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x-1.5$

You have to separate the terms an later use the chain rule

Answer (score 2):

First, write it as: $$2.5\sqrt{400-x^2}-1.5x+120.$$
Then from the properties of derivatives we have: $$\eqalign{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[2.5\sqrt{400-x^2}-1.5x+120\right]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}2.5\sqrt{400-x^2}+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[-1.5x+120\,\Big] \\ &=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}2.5(400-x^2)^{1/2}+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}-1.5x.
}$$
For the first one use the chain rule, for the second one it is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\sqrt{b - x^{m}}$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{b - x^{m}} &= \frac{d}{dx} (b - x^{m})^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} (b - x^{m})^{1/2 -1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x^{m}) \\
&= \frac{m}{2} \frac{ x^{m-1}}{\sqrt{b - x^{m}} }
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ a \sqrt{b-x^{m}} - cx + d \right] &= \frac{m}{2} \frac{ x^{m-1}}{\sqrt{b - x^{m}} } - c
\end{align} 
Letting $a=5/2$, $b=400$, $c=3/2$ and $d=120$ will provide the answer with the specific values.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it and use the chain rule

$$
2.5\cdot (400-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}+1.5\cdot 80-1.5\cdot x
$$
Taking the derivative like so

$$
2.5\cdot \frac{1}{2}(400-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (-2x)-1.5
$$
and simplify, using the exponent rule $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$

$$
-\frac{2.5 x}{\sqrt{400-x^2}}-1.5
$$